# The javascript isn't pushing all elements on the array, just one

Tags: javascript, arrays, scripting

I have a class that have 10 elements and when I push my array it is returning just one element. What is the issue with the script?

`function() {
var vins = document.querySelectorAll('.dws-vehicle-listing-item-field.dws-vehicle-field-vin');

```
for (var i = 0; i < vins.length; i++) {
    var array = [];
    var items = vins[i].innerText.replace(/ /g, "").split('\n')[2];
    array.push(items);
}
return array;
```

}`

I tried to add some exclusions based on code string, but even that it didn't work. Still returning just one element

Comment: Follow this guide on how to ask for future questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Without knowing what `vins` is I am guessing but when you call `[2]` you are selecting the 2nd item of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you are redeclaring a new array instance each time you loop. The solution is to initialise the array variable outside the loop;

```js
let array = [];
for (let i = 0; i < vins.length; i++) {
    let items = vins[i].innerText.replace(/ /g, "").split('\n')[2];
    array.push(items);
}
return array;
```

Also, I recommend you not to use `var`, but using `const` (for values which do not change) or `let` instead: [more on this](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/4-reasons-why-var-is-considered-obsolete-in-modern-javascript-a30296b5f08f)